# What tools/projects/integrations exist around Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How does the ecosystem around Anuglarjs look like?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of initiatives going on. Meetup groups are forming and if you are in bay area, I encourage you to attend the google sponsored angularjs ones (at google). Also you may want to monitor the angularjs googlegroup and github wiki. Since there has been a 1.0 production release (last week). You should see a lot of activity and more consistent messaging. The documentation is not complete, however, this should be remedied in the next few months. There are some great tutorials and examples. I would recommend looking at the 1.0 ones so as to not be confused with deprecated and possibly totally out of date apis.

Google is working on a Chrome Extension for angular that will let you much more easily debug and check performance. There has been IDE integration with Webstorm and Netbeans.  NOTE: I cannot speak to what the current status of these are.

Some community members are working on a .NET NUGET package to setup VS solutions. An angular-ui group (i am member) is starting to create new and wrap existing popular UI plugins in jquery-ui and twitter bootstrap.

Google has also created a http://builtwith.angularjs.org/ site to show case projects. Now that there is a stable release expect to see a lot more happen.

hope this helps.

Comment: The Chrome Extension was released 7/2/2012: [Batarang](http://blog.angularjs.org/2012/07/introducing-angularjs-batarang.html)